# Problem in harmonic series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, roots

If the sum of roots of the quadratic equation $ax^2 +bx+c=0$

{ $(a,b,c)$  not equal to zero}

is equal to sum of squares of their reciprocals ,  then $a/c$   ,  $b/a$,  $c/b$ are in?

Actually the options given were  -

$a.p$  ,

$g.p$  ,

$h.p$

none of these.

I could make it out that $a.p$ and $g.p$ are not  the answers.

I know a little about harmonic series that it's like the reciprocal of an  arithmetic series  but i don't   know much  and hence couldn't solve it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can try to formulate your question in a more understandable English? Sorry but I didn't really get your question....

Answer (score 0):

$a \over c$, $b\over a$,$c\over b$ are in HP means that $c\over a$,$a\over b$,$b\over c$ are in AP.This should simplify things.
**Let the two roots be** $l$ **and** $m$ **then**:
 $$l+m={-b\over a}$$
$$l.m={c\over a}$$
$$l^2+m^2={{b^2\over a^2}-2*{c\over a}}$$
**If sum of roots is equal to sum of squares of their reciprocals then**:
$$l+m={{1\over l^2}+{1\over m^2}}$$
Solve this using the above 3 equations to get a relation between  $a/c,b/a,c/b$.